# SQL Server 2012 SP1+CU3 --> SQL Server 2012 SP2+CU1

Tags: sql-server-2012, patch, service-pack

We're currently on SQL Server 2012 SP1 + CU3. If I wanted to install SP2 + CU1 do I have to install SP1 CU11 first which I do believe is the last CU before SP2 or can I go ahead and install SP2 right away and then follow that with latest CU1 for SP2?

Thanks

Comment: No, if you install CU11 and then install SP2, you'll lose the fixes in CU11. If you then install SP2 CU1, you'll get a few of the CU11 fixes back, but not all of them. My suggestion: go to 2012 SP1 CU11 now, then go to SP2 and its CU2 when it is available.

Comment: can I install SP1 CU11 if I have already installed SP2 + CU1 or does it have to be in the right sequence without jumping back?

Comment: No, you cannot apply a CU for SP1 to SP2, or vice versa. Is there a specific fix you need from CU11? Which one?

Comment: Hey Aaron, no not really! I was just wondering if that was doable since you said once SP2 is installed I'll lose a few of the CU11 fixes. thanks for explaining this :-)